# TYPO3 FLUIDTEMPLATE How to switch between different backend layouts and only switch between the templates, not the layouts?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

I have following Typoscript for switching backend layout:

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        templateName = TEXT
        templateName {
            cObject = TEXT
            cObject {
                data = pagelayout
                required = 1
                case = uppercamelcase
                split {
                    token = pagets__
                    cObjNum = 1
                    1.current = 1
                }
            }
            ifEmpty = Default
        }
        
        templateRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:package/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
            1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.templateRootPath}
        }
        partialRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
            1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath}
        }
        layoutRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:package/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
            1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.layoutRootPath}
        }
    ...
```

My goal is: I have different backend layouts, like 2 columns, three columns...
When I switch, I want to load 2Columns.html or 3Columns.html from the Resources/Private/**Templates**/Page/, but keep the Default.html (Main Layout of the Website) in Resources/Private/**Layouts**/Page/. But I always get the error:
The Fluid template files "/package/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/2Columns" could not be loaded.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: This TypoScript-Snippet should only switch the template. Via TypoScript you are *not* able to change layouts. The template itself always calls its layout via `<f:layout name="main" />`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, here was my mistake, I also changed the `<f:layout name="main" />` to `<f:layout name="2Columns" />`, now it is obvious, why it did not work

Answer (score 0):

The naming might be misleading.

**There are a lot of `templates` in the world of TYPO3:**

1. there are typoscript configurations which are called `template`. These consists of records (table `sys_template`) or files (`*.typoscript`)
2. there are HTML-files which includes pattern how the page should be generated (classical `HTML-template`)
   2.a. there are `marker-templates` for the old way
   2.b. there are `FLUID-templates`. These are divided into three categories which are stored in separate folders named for their purpose:
   2.b.I. Templates
   2.b.II. Partials
   2.b.III. Layouts

And with category 2.b.I. we get another `template`.

If you use FLUID the primary decision for an appearance of a page is done with the `template` you start with.
*Also that is the only entry in selecting any FLUID files.*
Inside this selected `template file` (= from the folder `Templates/`) you can select a `layout file`. With this concept you can have different appearances (e.g. one-, two-, three-columns) with common parts like header/ footer.
In the `layout file` you define those parts of a page which are common to different `templates`.

In the `partial files` you define smaller parts which can be used multiple times or which just make a separate unit (e.g. a menu, or the way you want to include images)

**The other non unique name is `layout`**:

Inside the `FLUID templates` we had the category `layout`(2.b.III)
but there also are fields in some records named `layout`: `tt_content.layout`, `pages.layout`, `pages.backend_layout`, `pages.backend_layout_next_level`
These **can** make a difference in the appearance of the data.
But that must be configured.

Your example uses `pagelayout` which gets filled from the fields `pages.backend_layout`, `pages.backend_layout_next_level` with inheritance and override, so you can easily use it. and correctly you select a (FLUID-)`template`.

---

So: your definition is correct.

You can not select `FLUID-layouts` from typoscript and you do not need it.

Comment: if it's helpful, join the gamification and accept the answer and/or upvote it.